# Installing it on no USB boot, no DVD PC?

Tags: system-installation

I want to install it on old celeron 3ghz that can't boot from USB (bios doesn't seem to support it) and has just CD not a DVD.
It currently runs XP.

What are my options here? It has a second HDD if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that it has a CD drive. This means you can easily use Minimal CD.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD